# Perl: Syntax error at strings.pl line 8, near ") {"

Tags: perl

Here is my code:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $s1 = "Hello";
my $s2 = "World\n";
my $s3 = $s1 . " " . $s2;
print $s3

if      ($s1 eq $s2) {print "same string\n"}
elsif ($s1 gt $s2) {print "$s1 is greater than $s2\n"}
elsif ($s1 lt $s2) {print "$s1 is less than $s2\n"}
```

But every time that I try to run this, I get this error,

> syntax error at strings.pl line 8, near ") {"

I don't understand why I'm getting it.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon: `print $s3` should be `print $s3;`

Comment: If you're curious why perl points to the line containing `) {` instead of the line that's actually missing the semicolon, I *think* it's because when there the parser gets to the `if` after the `print` without encountering an intervening semicolon, it expects the `if` to be a [statement modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) as opposed to a [compound statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a ";" after "print $s3"

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $s1 = "Hello";
my $s2 = "World\n";
my $s3 = $s1 . " " . $s2;
print $s3; 

if      ($s1 eq $s2) {print "same string\n"}
elsif ($s1 gt $s2) {print "$s1 is greater than $s2\n"}
elsif ($s1 lt $s2) {print "$s1 is less than $s2\n"}
```